# Removed trusted CA's now can't use Google.........Anything!

Tags: google-play-store, restore, certificates, https

My boyfriend accidently hit the 'Remove all stored credentials' and now he can not access anything Google, but most importantly the Play Store.

OK it might have been on purpose, don't ask, but now it's (as usual) up to me to fix it and really I don't have a clue what to do.
I have been searching and searching for an answer and have tried many different fixes, none of which have worked obviously.
I guess I'm asking if there is an updated list of Stock Trusted CA's or certificates or SSL's or whatever they are, that come with the most current Android OS? This is specifically for a Motorola Xoom Tablet but that shouldn't matter because this list i'm hoping for would be for Any Android device.
And....
If this is not what/where I should be looking into/at in relevance to making Google 'work' again, what should I be doing?

Thanks for any and All help in advance!

Oh, and No, this is Not a rooted device, I don't think that would be a good idea for him right now!  :-)